# duplicate import using same common component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In a page I need to have multiple modals, and I did this

```
import ApproveModal from '~/components/common/modal'
import RejectModal from '~/components/common/modal'

this.setState({ openApproveModal: true })
{openApproveModal && <ApproveModal />

this.setState({ openRejectModal: true })
{openRejectModal && <RejectModal />
```

Not sure this is the correct way to do it but I saw possible of having duplicated codes, what if I have 3-4 actions, I need to import 4 confirmation modals?

Comment: You can import only once, and can pass current state of which modal to show like ModalState: 'RejectModal' to that component i.e: <Modal state={this.state.ModalState} /> and render based on that.

Comment: @vijay22uk the content of each action is different.

Comment: than your modal component can return content/ suitable component based on passed current state or you can export multiple components for modal and can use import destructuring

Comment: @vijay22uk so you want to duplicate the code? nah that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your `modal` component, just export multiple instances of various modals:

`export { ApproveModal, DeclineModal };`

Then just import them using the very useful destructuring pattern (more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

`import { ApproveModal, DeclineModal } from '~/components/common/modal';`

Comment: modal is a shared component, I don't know what a modal will be